# How to add Google Game Service to AIR AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, google-app-engine, air, flash-cs6

Does anyone have any idea on how this can be done? I want the high score leaderboards.  I've literally searched everywhere and cant find any Google Play Game Service ANE Native extensions. I want to add it to my AIR project I'm using Flash CS6 with Flash Develop.

Answer (score 0):

Distriqt are the first to create such an extension, and there is none at this point. Keep track of their work - it's in progress and it's said it will be available soon:

http://distriqt.uservoice.com/forums/199650-general/suggestions/4468643-gamecenter-googleplaygames-ane

Comment: Well not necessarily. I found this method from FreshPlanet and it works for others but I am having trouble using it. https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Google-Play-Game-Services/    also its free.

Comment: Also I have a feeling that distriqt will charge it with a bundle for like 100 bucks or something. Thats just too much to spend on a bundle if you only need one ANE.

Comment: Hi, when this extension gets released it will be for sale individually. We are hoping to release an initial version soon.